# Trying to upload images into Firebase error: Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL' - SWIFT 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I know there have been 2 other questions like this one (linked below), and I have tried for hours trying to apply the solutions for my code but haven't been successful at it. I am trying to build my backend for my app and want to upload multiple images to Firebase as one single 'post' exactly like Instagram's feature where you do the same. The code below is my ImageUploadManager witch is intended to handle the photos being uploaded to Firebase in the 'multiple images in one post' way for my practice project.

Links to other 2 questions: 
[Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448396/value-of-type-storagemetadata-has-no-member-downloadurl)

[StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546796/storagemetadata-has-no-member-downloadurl)

```
    import UIKit
    import FirebaseStorage
    import Firebase

    struct Constants {

        struct Car {
            static let imagesFolder: String = "carImages"
        }

    }

    class ImageUploadManager: NSObject {
                                    //Below code (comented out) is for completion progress visual
        func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, /**/ progressBlock: @escaping (_ percentage: Double) -> Void, /**/ completionBlock: @escaping (_ url: URL?, _ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
            let storage = Storage.storage()
            let storageReference = storage.reference()

            //storage/carImages/{customId}/image.jpg
            let imageName = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg"
            let imagesReference = storageReference.child(Constants.Car.imagesFolder).child(imageName)

            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) {
                let metadata = StorageMetadata()
                metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"

                let uploadTask = imagesReference.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                //Lines below may also be for progress bar not sure
                    if let metadata = metadata {
 //Error here           completionBlock(metadata.downloadURL(), nil)
                    } else {
                        completionBlock(nil, error?.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    //ends here
                })
                uploadTask.observe(.progress, handler: { (snapshot) in
                    //Below lines for Progress bar on upload
                    guard let progress = snapshot.progress else {
                        return
                    }

                    let percentage = (Double(progress.completedUnitCount) / Double(progress.totalUnitCount)) * 100
                    progressBlock(percentage)
                    //Ends here
                })
            } else {
                completionBlock(nil, "Image could not be converted to Data.")
            }
        }

    }
```

UPADTED CODE WITH ANSWER BELOW: Ive replaced my old 'let uploadTask = ' with his solution

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage
import Firebase

struct Constants {

    struct Car {
        static let imagesFolder: String = "carImages"
    }

}

class ImageUploadManager: NSObject {
                                //Below code (comented out) is for completion progress visual
    func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, /**/ progressBlock: @escaping (_ percentage: Double) -> Void, /**/ completionBlock: @escaping (_ url: String?, _ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageReference = storage.reference()

        //storage/carImages/{customId}/image.jpg
        let imageName = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg"
        let imagesReference = storageReference.child(Constants.Car.imagesFolder).child(imageName)

        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) {
            let metadata = StorageMetadata()
            metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"

            //        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).png")

            let uploadTask = imagesReference.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if let metadata = metadata {
                    imagesReference.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                        guard let downloadURL = url else {
                            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                            return
                        }
                    }
                    completionBlock(downloadURL, nil)
                } else {
                    completionBlock(nil, error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
            uploadTask.observe(.progress, handler: { (snapshot) in
                guard let progress = snapshot.progress else {
                    return
                }

                let percentage = (Double(progress.completedUnitCount) / Double(progress.totalUnitCount)) * 100
                progressBlock(percentage)

            })
        } else {
            completionBlock(nil, "Image could not be converted to Data.")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The download URL is no longer available on the `metadata` object. Instead you call `download URL` on the `StorageReference` after the upload has completed.

```
let uploadTask = imagesReference.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
    if let metadata = metadata {
        imagesReference.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            guard let downloadURL = url else {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                return
            }
        }
        completionBlock(downloadURL, nil)
    } else {
        completionBlock(nil, error?.localizedDescription)
    }
})
```

Note that this is a pretty direct copy from the documentation, so I recommend studying that a bit more too: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory

Comment: Thanks for answer, I replaced my 'let uploadTask = imagesReference.putData(imageData, ....etc ' with the code you sent, but now I get this error " Use of unresolved identifier 'downloadURL' " , did I implement your solution wrongly? and/or how do I fix this? thanks in advance!